# WaitGroup - fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: go, deadlock, waitgroup

Can someone explain why this code throws an "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"?

I can't seem to find what is wrong. I've seen some questions about this specific error, but the reason was mostly looping through a channel without closing it.
Thank you!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ch := make(chan time.Duration)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, v := range []time.Duration{5, 1} {
        wg.Add(1)
        go wait(v, ch, wg)
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}

func wait(seconds time.Duration, c chan time.Duration, wg sync.WaitGroup) {

    defer wg.Done()

    time.Sleep(seconds * time.Second)

    c <- seconds
}
```

Comment: Does [Why is there a deadlock in my code even after closing the channel and all workers quitting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53762085/5728991) answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass the `WaitGroup` by reference, not by value. Otherwise the `Done` has no effect. The [documentation of this type](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup) says:

> A WaitGroup must not be copied after first use.

Fix your code to this and it will work:

```
func main() {

    ch := make(chan time.Duration)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, v := range []time.Duration{5, 1} {
        wg.Add(1)
        go wait(v, ch, &wg)
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}

func wait(seconds time.Duration, c chan time.Duration, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    defer wg.Done()

    time.Sleep(seconds * time.Second)

    c <- seconds
}
```

---

It is also common to express this pattern as follows:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan time.Duration)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, v := range []time.Duration{5, 1} {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            wait(v, ch)
        }()
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}

func wait(seconds time.Duration, c chan time.Duration) {
    time.Sleep(seconds * time.Second)
    c <- seconds
}
```

What's nice about this case is that `wait` doesn't have to be aware of any wait groups (it could be a 3rd-party function, for example), and there's no confusion about passing a wait group by value or reference.

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question about this code. I expected the wait which takes 1 second to finish before the one which takes 5, however they seem to be running synchronous waiting for one another. 

How could I use goroutines to run them in parallel but waiting for all goroutines to finish before moving on?

Comment: @xohr: note that your loop launches the goroutines in order, not simultaneously. This is because the read `<-ch` is synchronizing. I would recommend having one loop to launch the goroutines, and then another loop to read everything from `ch`. Then the goroutines would run concurrently

Comment: @xohr: this is a relevant example: https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools

Comment: where would I be closing the channel to avoid another deadlock when taking values from an open channel in the loop? Shouldn't the goroutines close the channel? Then again - it would have to be last one that closes it, or am i wrong?

Comment: @xohr: where are you closing the channel now? :) The question for "when to close the channel" is complicated, since it depends on who the consumer is and who the producer is and how you coordinate between them. Probably worth a separate question with a clear and concrete use case explained (as in, what you're trying to achieve)

Comment: I am not closing the channel right now because I am not looping through it, I was referencing your suggestion "and then another loop to read everything from ch" which sounded to me like doing "for v := range ch" which would in turn cause a deadlock because I am not closing it. But i assume you didn't mean that. 

Thank you for your helpful advice! :)