# How do I avoid deadlocks and silent errors when using select?

Tags: go, switch-statement, runtime-error, deadlock

I am [learning Go by example](https://gobyexample.com/select). I've just implemented a select to await multiple channels as follows:

```
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        select {
        case msg1 := <-c1:
            fmt.Println("received", msg1)
        case msg2 := <-c2:
            fmt.Println("received", msg2)
        }
    }
```

With a little experimentation I've found that I can naively introduce runtime errors as follows:

- If I reduce i to 1, the first message is received, but the second is silently lost (there is no indication that I unwittingly ignored it).
- If I increase i to 3, both messages are received but I get `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

[Reading ahead](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups) and [searching for that error message on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68120886/236081) I can see that WaitGroups account for these types of issues. But they don't seem to apply to `select`, so I feel like I must be missing something.

Is there a language construct (like `if/then/else`) or software pattern that I can use to prevent or mitigate against these errors in real-world code?

Comment: There are infinite ways you could write logic errors in your program which the language cannot prevent. Concurrency just exposes another dimension for you to write those errors, but fundamentally this is no different than not dividing by zero, or not dereferencing nil pointers -- you need to write correct logic to begin with.

Comment: FWIW I think this is a reasonable question for someone still learning the language - the answer is certainly helpful to me - I can't see obvious ways to improve the quality of the question, but suggestions are welcome

Comment: @lofidevops I think wording like "easily introduce runtime errors" and "but the second [message] is lost silently" is possibly being taken as a slight against Go. In both cases you're kind of misrepresenting things. Of course you can "easily" introduce runtime errors in any language, this isn't surprising, and your second message isn't "silently lost", *you ignored it*. That's like reading half a file, *choosing* to stop reading the remainder of the file, and then claiming the second half of the file is "silently lost" as if this is somehow the language's fault (FWIW I did not downvote).

Comment: @meagar Thanks for the feedback. I've tried tweaking my wording to make it clearer I'm trying to anticipate MY errors and understand `select` better, rather than complaining about language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually you mitigate against this by designing software correctly. If you have two channels, and each channel will receive at most one message, don't try to read from them 3 times. This is no different than trying to put three items in a two element array, or trying to divide two numbers where the divisor is 0. In all these cases languages offer ways of discovering and recovering from the error, but if you're actually producing these errors, it indicates a logic or design flaw.

You need to make sure that your channels have a balanced number of reads and writes, and that the sending end closes the channel when it has nothing else to send so receivers can stop waiting for messages that won't come. Otherwise you'll eventually have something stuck waiting, or messages in a buffer that are ignored.

In this very specific case, if you want to read from both channels but only if a message is ready, you can add a `default` case which will be invoked if no channel is ready for reading, but that's for situations where your channels are not ready *yet* but will eventually *become* ready. Providing a `default` is not a good solution to cover over bugs where channels will *never* become ready yet you're still trying to read from them; that indicates a logic-level flaw that needs to be fixed.

Comment: thanks for helping me distinguish language features from logic errors - it looks like timeouts are another helpful tool when using select

Comment: @lofidevops They can be, but again, only if used logically correctly. You wouldn't use a timeout to cover for the fact that your channels won't be receiving any more information, and were left open when they should have been closed.